# 55" 4k moving picture display device without bells and whistles

Tags: monitors

Must not have:

- smart features (Android, WebOS etc.)
- webcam and mic

Must have:

- Between 55" and 65" panel
- 4k (2160p) resolution
- At least 3 HDMI inputs
- Reaction time good enough for games
- VESA mount
- Decent upscaler
- Available as factory new device on the European market
- Price under 2000€

Nice to have:

- Scart and composite input for old consoles
- Ambient light
- Speakers with acceptable quality
- Picture-in-Picture

I don't care:

- Any antenna interfaces and tuners
- 3D
- Network interfaces

Use cases:

- Play back any media via connected media center PC
- Play games via steam on PC
- Connect any kind of consoles from PS4 to NES

Trivia:

- I'm aware that's not very likely that I'll get a super good panel for this price
- My main concern is that all this TV software seems very fragile so I don't want to risk the leakage of any data. I guess that it could be secure enough to just not use insecure features like build-in network and antenna interfaces.
- I also tend to express my disapproval against such technologies by not buying it at all.

Comment: You're going to be hard pressed to find all of those features without Smart functions/features. They tend to package it in any TV with decent specs these days whether or not you want it.

Comment: I'd try one of the korean brands - I know crossover goes up to 40 inches, I have one of their 24 inchers and it does 4k with 3 hdmi 2.0 outputs. And you want HDMI 2.0 for 4k60